# Custom gradle plugin extension field value fetched is null

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have created a custom gradle plugin - `TaskConfigPlugin`

`Gradle Version: 1.12/2.0`  *(Can't upgrade as of now due to Org    restrictions)*

`Java Version: 1.8`

My Plugin code is as follows - `TaskConfigPlugin.java` >>

```
public class TaskConfigPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    private String taskPrefix;
    private Task mainTask;

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        TaskConfigPluginExtension extension = project.getExtensions()
                .create("taskOrder", TaskConfigPluginExtension.class);

        this.taskPrefix = extension.getTaskPrefix(); //the taskPrefix fetched is null
        this.mainTask = extension.getMainTask(); //mainTask fetched is null

        configureTaskOrdering(project);
    }


    private void configureTaskOrdering(Project project){
        // My Logic to order the task using 'dependsOn', 'mustRunAfter' etc
        // It uses the 'taskPrefix' to fetch all matching tasks and then 
        // establish the relationship with the 'mainTask'
    }
}
```

The extension object - `TaskConfigPluginExtension.java` >>

```
public class TaskConfigPluginExtension {

    private String taskPrefix;
    private Task mainTask;

    // getters and setters for the above

}
```

I have added the plugin info in the `META-INF/gradle-plugins/TaskConfigPlugin.properties`
which contains the full package name of the Plugin.

The plugin is being consumed as follows in my gradle - `mainConsumer.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir name: 'libs', dirs: 'lib/'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':TaskConfigPlugin:1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'TaskConfigPlugin'

task mainConsumer

taskOrder {
    taskPrefix = 'setup'
    mainTask = mainConsumer
}
```

Now when I run my consuming gradle `mainConsumer.gradle`, I see that the `taskPrefix` and `mainTask` values fetched are NULL. I understand that they belong to the `CONFIGURATION` phase and hence the values cannot be fetched earlier. But I tried with the `project.afterEvaluate` option and that is also NOT working for me.

There are some solutions (hoping they work) in terms of `Provider` and `Property` but I can't use them since they have been introduced with higher gradle versions, I guess `4.+`

So, is there some solution or workaround for me with `gradle 1.12` to fetch the extension values in the `CONFIGURATION` phase itself ?

Appreciate your response.
Thanks in advance.